# Are orders being resent to the exchanges everyday?

Tags: stocks

If someone placed a GTC order yesterday and I place one prior market open today. Assuming same broker (same execution speed), does his order gets filled before me since it was already in the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Good 'Til Cancelled (GTC) order  remains on the order book until  completely executed, canceled or when the security (such as an option) expires.

If you place a limit order at the same price for the same execution (both buying or both selling) then the GTC takes precedence.  However, if the GTC order has attached conditions then it's possible that your order could be filled first.  For example, you are next in line on the order book and the GTC order is AON (all or none) and your order is  for a smaller amount of shares than the GTC order.

Comment: "If I update an order, my previous order will get cancelled first before the new order being sent and I lose my precedence (order time being reset)." Is the statement correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.